# Existence of tags in relation to acceptability of questions

Tags: discussion

On a couple of occasions I or others have voted to close a question off-topic and the poster has responded by saying that the tag he has used exists and therefore he assumed the topic of the question was valid. The most [recent example](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70180/how-many-calories-does-an-adult-male-goat-need-per-day) was in relation to the tag ‘animal husbandry’.

Now I am aware that a question can be off-topic even if the subject of the tag is valid, but in this case there was a statement that animal husbandry was off topic. Perhaps that is wrong, or perhaps the problem is that people with a relatively low reputation (300) create new tags to fit a question and that those that are inappropriate escape the tag review process for some reason (lack of personel, low priority?. I am quite unfamiliar with the procedure. Is the system working properly or is there a need for change.

Comment: I'm probing more than proposing. Really hoping the mods who handle these things can say how things are from their perspective. In specific instances, e.g. this case of animal husbandry (which I didn't originate) your suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Wrapped my comments up into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a reasonable first pass to deciding whether a tag should possibly be removed is to ask:

*What do you think of the existing questions with that tag (both in quality of question and applicability of the tag)?*

I don't know what guidelines the moderators actually follow with respect to tag removal, but I'm guessing it's something similar to what I just suggested.

As far as the particular post you mention, I think @anongoodnurse really meant to say not that animal husbandry is off-topic, but rather that *simply being about animal husbandry* does not make a question on-topic - it needs to be something about biology.

"Food" is another, more-popular example. There are lots of on-topic questions about food, but not all questions about food are on-topic. Posting a question that applies to an existing tag does not make it on topic.

I know you have run into a similar issue with the "terminology" tag when you vote to close a question that is mostly about etymology. If there isn't biological basis for the question, it's off-topic, but terminology questions can be on-topic, as well, so the tag should stay.

Overall, **I think we could do a better job explaining in our comments why a particular post is not on-topic**, especially for new users. Where appropriate, this could include a brief explanation of the (lack of a) role for tags in determining on-topicness.